# Jackrabbit query on jcr:content

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr-sql2

I am using jackrabbit 2.6 and I have the following nodes structure

```
[nt:file]  
  |-- [nt:file]
         |-- [nt:resource]
```

In nt:resource nodetype there is property "jcr:data" with the stream of the file that I want to save.

I do not know how to create the query in order to retrieve all nt:resource nodes by content.

If did this query

```
select * from [nt:resource] as r 
where contains(r.[jcr:content], '*tristique*')
```

but it returns an empty result. What am I missing ?
Is the search-by-content enabled by default in jackrabbit ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that jackrabbit was not indexing plain text files because the encoding was not persisted.

I added:

```
node.setProperty(JcrConstants.JCR_ENCODING, encoding);
```

and now text files are indexed and full text search works fine.